# Wildfly classloader not find jar in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven, jar, wildfly

I am attempting to run this [JPBM6 Example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/jbpm6/jbpm-6-web-application-example). I am running Wildfly 8.1.0 Final; this is the version comes packaged with the official JBPM6 demo. I can successful build the war file, but when I deploy I get the following error in the stack trace when I try to deploy

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/kie/api/runtime/manager/RuntimeManager;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
```

I inspected the war and it contains the following jar: `WEB-INF/lib/kie-api-6.0.1.Final.jar` which contains the `org/kie/api/runtime/manager/RuntimeManager` interface class file. Is there some WildFly setting that is preventing the loading of that jar(s) from the class path? Could this be a poorly phrased error stating that it could not find an implementation class, if so does anyone know what maven dependency might be missing from the example pom file?

Comment: It should definitely find any libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`. Have you tried 8.2.0.Final just check?

Comment: This problem appears to be a caused by my deployment process using Eclipse. I using using the Servers view and using the 'Add and Remove' to deploy the webapp. When I did a Run As / Maven install and manually deployed the war through the WildFly console this issue went away. I was having other deployment/environment problems, but this one went away when I did as a manual deployment.